# How to Convert Between Timezones in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timezone

am building a livescore but the API am using is returning time that is 2hrs ahead of my local time, and I can't convert it to my country's time since different users from different countries will be accessing the livescore. I don't know the api timezone.. But I want a function that will get the api timezone and convert to the user's local time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For http://momentjs.com users, you can now use

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/.

Using it, your function would look something like this:

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD/HH:mm:ss ZZ'; 
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentjs .  Example fiddle `

```js
var serverdate = "Fri Jun 15 2018 08:03:23 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"

var date3 =  moment(serverdate) // this will automatically convert the date to the time zone on  user's machine

alert(date3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

`